# добавить 1 к урл пагинации Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Привет,

Подскажите, как можно заменить урл http://test.com/page/10 на http://test.com/page/11. То есть добавить 1?
Использую php и WP.

получаю ссылки и как добавить 1 не получается.

```
function add_prev_next_links() {
    global $post;


    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $ur = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        preg_match('#page/(\d+)#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match_page);
        $paged = $match_page[1];

        if($paged){
            echo '<link rel="next" href="' . $ur .'" />' . "\n";
            echo '<link rel="prev" href="' . $ur . '" />' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_prev_next_links');
```

Comment: Инкрементировать переменную match_page - не?

Comment: в пхп на данный момент не силен, много чего не знаю. За ответ спасибо, попробую.

Comment: с инкрементом понял, а как перезаписать?

Comment: перезаписать что? :)

Comment: $ur = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        preg_match('#page/(\d+)#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ++$match_page);

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_prev_next_links() {
    global $wp_query;

    if (is_front_page()) {
        $currentPage = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $link = get_page_link();

        if ($currentPage > 1) {
            echo '<link rel="prev" href="' . $link . 'page/' . ($currentPage-1) . '" />' . "\n";
        }

        if ($currentPage < $wp_query->max_num_pages) {
            echo '<link rel="next" href="' . $link . 'page/' . ($currentPage+1) . '" />' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_prev_next_links');
```

Comment: Не уверен, что понятна суть вопроса. Как на него можно было дать столь подробный ответ? :)

Comment: В моем случае это не работает, к сожалению. Сайт сделан немного коряво(

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
function add_prev_next_links() {
    global $post;


    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $ur = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        preg_match('#page/(\d+)#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match_page);
        $paged = $match_page[1];
        $x = $match_page[1] + 1;
        $software = str_replace($match_page[1], $x, $ur);
        if($paged){
            echo '<link rel="next" href="' . $software .'" />' . "\n";
            echo '<link rel="prev" href="' . $ur . '" />' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_prev_next_links');
```